# Can C++11's bind-functions be used in an std (or even better an mtl) vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, bind, std

I'm trying to save different random variables (well the problem is, they aren't variables, but functions) to a vector:

```
auto dW0 = std::bind(std::normal_distribution<double>{0.0, 1}, std::default_random_engine{123456});
auto dW1 = std::bind(std::normal_distribution<double>{0.0, 1}, std::default_random_engine{123456+1000});

std::vector<decltype(dW0)> dW = {dW0, dW1};
```

It would be even better if I could save these to an mtl-vector:

```
mtl::dense_vector<decltype(dW0)> dW = {dW0, dW1};
```

But saving them to an std-vector would help a lot.

Comment: They can't really be stored directly, since it's not guaranteed that they even have the same type (in your case, you're lucky, since the types of the arguments are the same for both invocations). Wrap them in `std::function`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result type of `bind` can be stored in a `vector`, since C++11 20.8.9.1.2 specifies that it is `MoveConstructible` (and also `CopyConstructible`, if the bound functor and arguments are).

But note that the result type of `bind` will be different when binding different functor and argument types; and all the objects in a vector must have the same type. In your example, that's fine; but if you need more flexibility (such as different distributions or engines) then you'll need to store a more generic functor type like `std::function`.

I'm not familiar with `mtl::dense_vector`, but hopefully it has compatible requirements to `std::vector`, in which case that should also be fine.